# How to get more info on a boost::xml_archive exception

Tags: c++, boost, xml-serialization

Hi I have written some code that is serializing some object to xml and then trying to deserialize it from a file. This has been working but suddenly I am getting a

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error
```

So I guess I must have made a breaking change somewhere. The problem is boost is not giving me any more information, is there any way (perhaps compiler flag?) to get more information on the error?

I am using G++, and boost v1.46

Comment: ...probably the output stream parameter has some kind of problem. If really wanna know what is happening, you can compile both (your program and boost) in debug mode and then check what is going on...

Comment: did you read the [**documentation**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/exceptions.html#input_stream_error)?

Answer (score 0):

You may enclose the archive function in a try catch block and do logging in case of an exception.

I have done this:

```
#if LIBRARY_DEBUG
    #define ARCHIVE_TRY try {
    #define ARCHIVE_CATCH } \
        catch(const std::exception& e) { \
            STACK_TRACE; \
            LOG_ERROR(std::string("Exception: "  + e.what())); \
            throw e; \
        }
#else
    #define ARCHIVE_TRY
    #define ARCHIVE_CATCH
#endif
```